# Google Cloud Print: simplest possible client

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, google-cloud-print

Looking into using Google Cloud Print, it seems that it is quite complicated regarding OAuth2, the various tokens/client ids etc.

What is the simplest possible way to print a PDF from a web page?

- Implemented client side in Javascript with AJAX (so with CORS) or server side with Java (but preferrably not too many jars needed)
- PDF document can be sent as binary or referred to as publicly available URL
- Preferrably no user login, must be with some kind of "service" authorization

The same application is already using API keys for google maps geocoding. So re-using these keys, if possible, would be the ideal option.

It would be great with some pointers on how to do this in the simplest possible manner possible.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest possible scenario is using the GCP Web Element, as described in: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/gadget

It boils down to including the print gadget scripts, creating a container to host the button and creating the print gadget in it:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="print_button_container"></div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/cloudprint/client/cpgadget.js">
</script>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
    gadget.setPrintButton(
        cloudprint.Gadget.createDefaultPrintButton("print_button_container")); // div id to contain the button
    gadget.setPrintDocument("url", "Test Page", "https://www.google.com/landing/cloudprint/testpage.pdf");
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are not logged-in your GCP account you will be shown the appropriate log-in dialog and then you'll select the target printer.

Check the fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/0ncsuqra/